# Not able to access AWS DynamoDb from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Not able to access AWS DynamoDb from Lambda function.

Lambda function:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});

const getUser = async function () {
    console.log('getUser() invoked');
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const params = {
        TableName: 'Users',
        Key: {
          "UserId": "A001"
        }
    };
    console.log('params ', params);
    documentClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
        console.log('============>');
        if (err) {
            console.log('error ', err);
            return err;
        }
        console.log('success ', data);
        return data;
    });
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    console.log('event ', event);
    const data = await getUser();
    console.log('=============> data ', data);
};
```

While testing Lambda function, data is printing undefined. it is printing params but not printing error and success.

Comment: Any errors in CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to use a VPC? If so, this means it does not have Internet access unless a NAT Gateway or VPC Endpoint is provided.

Comment: No lambda function is not configured to use a VPC. I am trying in AWS management console. Do i need to configure VPC in AWS console ?

Comment: No error is being reported in CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

you're making some confusing about callbacks and promises here, the way you have now you are not passing the data outside.

```
const getUser = async function () {
  console.log('getUser() invoked');
  const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const params = {
      TableName: 'Users',
      Key: {
        "UserId": "A001"
      }
  };
  console.log('params ', params);
  try {
    const data = await documentClient.get(params).promise();
    console.log('============>');
    console.log('success ', data);
    return data;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('error ', err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

[to more about callback and promises check](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)